# Node.js receive form data sent from frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

node.js server

```
app.post('/create-checkout-session', (req,res) =>{
  console.log(req.form);
  console.log(req.body);
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: "price_id",
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    metadata: {
      id: 1,
      email: "soubhagya",
    },
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: `https://www.youtube.com/?success=true`,
    cancel_url: `https://www.youtube.com/?canceled=true`,
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
})
```

React frontend

```
      <form
          action="http://localhost:4000/create-checkout-session"
          method="POST"
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            name="user"
            value={"hellowowowowowo"}
            disabled
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="w-32 text-white bg-primary-purple hover:bg-primary-700 font-medium rounded-sm text-sm p-4 xs:w-full"
          >
            GET STARTED
          </button>
        </form>
```

Here is my code where i am sending some data to baackend. but,In backend i am not getting any data.
How can i receive form data in backend ?

Please take a loook

Answer (score 1):

- Did you set JSON parse on app.js?
- Did you correct API endpoint? It seems you did not miss the api/payment.
  I think you defined routes.js or something file as a pre-url.
  Please make sure.
- check your browser console and network to confirm the requirements with data to the back end.

Comment: Every thing is fine. For question i added by copy pasting

Answer (score 0):

Your backend looks fine, but instead of using forms actions to send request, why not use the onSubmit event. It should look something like that:

```js
<form onSubmit={() => fetch('http://localhost:4000/create-checkout-session'), {method: 'POST', body: YOUR CONTENT HERE}}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="user"
            value={"hellowowowowowo"}
            disabled
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="w-32 text-white bg-primary-purple hover:bg-primary-700 font-medium rounded-sm text-sm p-4 xs:w-full"
          >
            GET STARTED
          </button>
        </form>
```

I used the fetch method in my example, but you can use any library that you want (Axios for example).